# CSS block works only if typed twice

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code with CSS (I tried it with a separate CSS file as well, so the problem is somewhere else). The only block that doesn't work is

```css
tr:hover {
    color:black;
    background-color: palevioletred;
    font-size:120%; 
}
```

but when I copy-paste the same block (see below), that works O.o Does anyone know what the heck?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css">
    </head>
    
    <style>

   th {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #CCC}
//odd or even 

tr:hover {
    color:black;
    background-color: palevioletred;
    font-size:120%; 
}
        
tr:hover {
    color:black;
    background-color: palevioletred;
    font-size:120%; 
}

    </style>
    
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  
         <tr id="row">
            <th>Header: This is row1 column1</th>
            <th>Header: This is row1 column2</th>
         </tr>
         <tr id="row">
            <td>This is row2 column1</td>
            <td>This is row2 column2</td>
         </tr>
   <tr id="row">
            <td>This is row3 column1</td>
            <td>This is row3 column2</td>
         </tr>
    <tr id="row">
            <td>This is row4 column1</td>
            <td>This is row4 column2</td>
         </tr>
    <tr id="row">
            <td>This is row5 column1</td>
            <td>This is row5 column2</td>
         </tr>
    <tr id="row">
            <td>This is row6 column1</td>
            <td>This is row6 column2</td>
         </tr>
    <tr id="row">
            <td>This is row7 column1</td>
            <td>This is row7 column2</td>
         </tr>
    <tr id="row">
            <td>This is row8 column1</td>
            <td>This is row8 column2</td>
         </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `//odd or even` is not a correct comment sytax for CSS. It should be `/*odd or even*/`. Also, you are using the same `id` on every row.... `id` should be unique.

Comment: Damn, it worked, thanks!

Comment: I thought that mistakes would be ignored :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment is not in the correct format.

The good format for comments in css is : `/* odd or even */`

Here is the working code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css">
</head>

<style>
  th {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #CCC
  }
  /* odd or even */
  
  tr:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: palevioletred;
    font-size: 120%;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

  <table style="width:100%">

    <tr id="row1">
      <th>Header: This is row1 column1</th>
      <th>Header: This is row1 column2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
      <td>This is row2 column1</td>
      <td>This is row2 column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row3">
      <td>This is row3 column1</td>
      <td>This is row3 column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row4">
      <td>This is row4 column1</td>
      <td>This is row4 column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row5">
      <td>This is row5 column1</td>
      <td>This is row5 column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row6">
      <td>This is row6 column1</td>
      <td>This is row6 column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row7">
      <td>This is row7 column1</td>
      <td>This is row7 column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row8">
      <td>This is row8 column1</td>
      <td>This is row8 column2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```